# Save state of custom filter on jQuery DataTable plugin

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables, savestate

I have custom jQuery datatable filter applied on my dynamic data which is coming from REST API result. the code is as below:

```
$('#jQmyCases').DataTable({ 
    //... All the required options are here ...
    // Fetch data from REST API
});
```

Once data are loaded, I initialize the my custom filter with below snippet:

```
$('#jQmyCases thead').append('<tr id="filters"><th col="ItemColor">Item Color</th><th>..</th>....</tr>'); // Many filters r there but i have only added one
```

First I append the filter string in `thead` then I bind custom filter a dropdwon with the available options from the received data, see below snippet:

```
$("#filters th").each(function (i) {
    var colheader = $(this).attr('col');
    var select = $('<select id="ddl' + colheader + '" style="width:80px;"><option value="">Selecteer ' + $(this).attr('col') + '</option></select>')
                    .appendTo($(this).empty())
                    .on('change', function () {
                        dataTableExample.column(i)
                       .search($(this).val())
                       .draw();
                    });


    dataTableExample.column(i).data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j, full) {
        try {
            if (full[j] != null) {
                if (i == 3) { // Column Color
                    var itemColor = full[j];
                    select.append('<option value="' + itemColor + '">' + itemColor + '</option>');
                }
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

Now I have to save state of the datatable so that in the next reload of the page, it does save the values of dropdown and show the previous results.

I have looked [here](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/12/save-custom-filter-state-jquery-data-tables/), which has shown some logic what I want but it has the static option as a filter.

**Question:** How can I achieve `saveState` option with my custom filter on jQuery dataTable plugin? Does anyone have workaround fro this?

Any help would be much appreciated.